# Get Max Date for prev months based on a given date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that will give me the `max date` form `Table_A` based on the following condition.

If the given date (input parameter) falls **between 01 April and 30 Sept** of that year then return `MAX(date)` prior to April 1.

OR

If the given date (input parameter) falls **between 01 Oct and 31 March** of the following year then return `MAX(date)` prior to Oct 1.

For example :

1. Given date is 27th Dec, 2012 (date between 01 Oct and 31 March of the following year)
   return 29th Sept, 2012
2. Given Date is  17th Aug, 2012 (date between 01 April and 30 Sept of the following year)
   return date (MAX DATE prior to is 01 April is 29th March)

Comment: "MAX DATE prior to is 01 April is 29th March" Why? MAX DATE prior to  01 April is 31 March!

Comment: I am trying the find the Max date from the records available in table_A not just max date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select max(case
            when trunc(the_date) between to_date('01-apr-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
                                     and to_date('30-sep-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
             and dte < to_date('01-apr-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
            then
              dte
            when trunc(the_date) between to_date('01-oct-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
                                     and to_date('31-mar-'||(the_year+1), 'dd-mon-yyyy')
             and dte < to_date('01-oct-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
            then
              dte
           end) max_date
  from table_a a 
       cross join (select v_inp_date the_date,
                          to_char(add_months(v_inp_date,-3), 'yyyy') the_year
                     from dual) dte;
```

so you input date is in the `dte` part

```
v_inp_date
```

and

```
 to_char(add_months(v_inp_date,-3), 'yyyy') the_year
```

eg a small test:

```
SQL> create table table_a(dte date);

    Table created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('28-sep-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('29-sep-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('28-mar-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('29-mar-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('28-sep-2011', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values(to_date('27-mar-2011', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> var inpdate varchar2(20);
SQL> exec :inpdate := '27-dec-2012';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select max(case
  2              when trunc(the_date) between to_date('01-apr-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
  3                                       and to_date('30-sep-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
  4               and dte < to_date('01-apr-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
  5              then
  6                dte
  7              when trunc(the_date) between to_date('01-oct-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
  8                                       and to_date('31-mar-'||(the_year+1), 'dd-mon-yyyy')
  9               and dte < to_date('01-oct-'||the_year, 'dd-mon-yyyy')
 10              then
 11                dte
 12             end) max_date
 13    from table_a a
 14         cross join (select to_date(:inpdate,'dd-mon-yyyy') the_date,
 15                            to_char(add_months(to_date(:inpdate,'dd-mon-yyyy'), -3), 'yyyy') the_year
 16                       from dual) dte;

MAX_DATE
---------
29-SEP-12

SQL> exec :inpdate := '17-aug-2012';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /

MAX_DATE
---------
29-MAR-12

SQL> exec :inpdate := '01-oct-2011';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /

MAX_DATE
---------
28-SEP-11

SQL> exec :inpdate := '01-apr-2011';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /

MAX_DATE
---------
27-MAR-11

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The end date in my example is Dec-31-2012, you can extend it to 2013+. I'm building table on the fly-the max_date is printed for every row. Also, I hardcode max dates. You do not need to do any of this, this is just for example. Replace &1 and &2 with values w/out quotes...:

```
SELECT date_table --, start_date, end_date
, (CASE WHEN date_table BETWEEN To_Date('01-APR-2012') And To_Date('30-SEP-2012') Then max_apr_date 
        WHEN date_table BETWEEN To_Date('01-OCT-2012') And To_Date('31-DEC-2012') Then max_oct_date
   END) max_date
FROM
(
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y')+LEVEL-1   date_table
        , To_Date('&1')                start_date  
        , To_Date('&2')                end_date 
        , '29-MAR-2012'                max_apr_date 
        , '29-Sep-2012'                max_oct_date
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),12)-TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y') )
  )
   WHERE date_table BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
)
/
```